# Trying to change the material md-selected tab using custom code from directive using two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm trying to change the tab using code and can't seem to figure out the error. The basic thing works if we use the controller to change the variable but when I try to bind it through directive, it brokes.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedTab = 0;
});
app.directive('something', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-click="changeNavigation()">Change Navigation</div>',
    scope: {
      selectedTab: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.changeNavigation = function() {
        console.log('Hello World');
        $scope.selectedTab = 2;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

You can view the working code with error on codepen: http://codepen.io/piyushchauhan2011/pen/rVRqeV?editors=101

The error is:
[image: Error for md-tabs]

Comment: In your example everthing is working fine

Comment: click on change navigation link. @Ankita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `selectedTab="selectedTab"` to `selected-tab="selectedTab"` while passing parameter to your directive.

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2yd9u7b9/

Comment: @PiyushChauhan, the fiddle I added uses 0.9.4. Which version are you targeting?

Comment: ohh I think then only on `0.10.0` it doesn't work, I updated my codepen version to `0.10.1`.