# Not able to shift tab having directive, using a button in md-tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design

I created multiple tabs using `md-tab`, and one in the middle had a directive.

I used the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595066/material-design-md-tabs-with-angularjs) question for going to the next tab using a next button below each tab.

below is the code -

**HTML**

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-tabs md-selected="selectedTab" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="Tab1">
            <md-content class="md-padding"> 
               <div class="tab-change-row">
                    <md-button class="tab-btn center-div md-raised" ng-click="changeTab()">Next</md-button>    
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Tab2">
            <md-content class="md-padding"> 
               <div class="tab-change-row">
                    <md-button class="tab-btn center-div md-raised" ng-click="changeTab()">Next</md-button>    
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Tab3">
            <md-content class="md-padding"> 
               <my-directive></my-directive>
               <div class="tab-change-row">
                    <md-button class="tab-btn center-div md-raised" ng-click="changeTab()">Next</md-button>    
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Tab4">
            <md-content class="md-padding"> 
               <div class="tab-change-row">
                    <md-button class="tab-btn center-div md-raised" ng-click="changeTab()">Next</md-button>    
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Tab5">
            <md-content class="md-padding"> 
               <div class="tab-change-row">
                    <md-button class="tab-btn center-div md-raised">Submit</md-button>    
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
     </md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

**CSS**

```
.center_div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width:80% /* value of your choice which suits your alignment */
}
.tab-change-row {
    text-align:center;
}
.tab-change-btn {
    display: inline-block
}
```

**Function in Controller**

```
$scope.selectedTab = 0;
$scope.changeTab = function() {
    console.log($scope.selectedTab);
    $scope.selectedTab++;
}
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('Myform', function () {
  return {
  controller: 'MyCtrl',
  replace: true,
  link: function($scope, element, attr, MyParentController) {
     element.append("<input name="Myinputfield"/>");
  }
});
```

When I hit the Next Button to move to the next tab it works fine, but the tab shift does not works after moving to the tab containing directive.

The `console.log` in the function prints -

```
0
1
0 //After moving to the tab containing the directive.
1 //These numbers after the second 0 are just number they don't shift the tab further.
2
3
4
5
6....
```

If i click on `Tab4` and the hit `Next`. Output of `console.log()` comes as `3`.

Everything works completely fine if I remove the directive tag.

So my observation states that selected is numbered as something like this-

**With Directive**

```
Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4, Tab5 -- (0,1,"Don't know, but why it shifts to this tab?",2,3)
```

**Without Directive**

```
Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4, Tab5 -- (0,1,2,3,4)
```

Any Solution for this issue would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be that `selectedTab` variable was not in the scope of the directive which created the issue.

The binding need to be done as a two-way binding. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933813/trying-to-change-the-material-md-selected-tab-using-custom-code-from-directive-u) question helped in understanding.

```
app.directive('Myform', function () {
  return {
  controller: 'MyCtrl',
  scope: {
      selectedTab: '='
    },
  replace: true,
  link: function($scope, element, attr, MyParentController) {
     element.append("<input name="Myinputfield"/>");
  }
});
```